# For a given sequence $\{a_n\}$ of real numbers, does the sequence $Sup \{a_k: k\geq n\} $ and $Inf\{a_k: k\geq n\} $ form a sub sequence of $\{a_n\}$

Tags: real-analysis

For a given sequence $\{a_n\}$ of real numbers, does the sequence $Sup \{a_k: k\geq n\} $ and $Inf\{a_k: k\geq n\} $ form a sub sequence of $\{a_n\}$

I ask this question because it's used to prove that if the sequence converges than $limsup$ and $liminf$ of the sequence also converges to same value (since sequence $Sup \{a_k: k\geq n\} $ and $Inf\{a_k: k\geq n\} $ are just subsequence of a convergent sequence).

I am not sure of this since $sup$ and $Inf$ of a set need not lie in the set. Please help me understand why they do in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily: if $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$, then $\inf\{a_k:k\geq n\}=0$ for all $n$, and the constant sequence $0$ is not a subsequence of $\{a_n\}$.

What is true is that there are subsequences of $\{a_n\}$ converging to $\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n$ and $\liminf_{n\to\infty}a_n$, provided that $\pm\infty$ are considered to be possible subsequential limits.